teams toolkit deploy failed with node-fetch
I have created a new app using VSCode teams tools kit v5.8.1
The app is the bot application connected to Function app
when I start debugging by clinking both debug in teams and debug in test tools
I got errors as below
I used the extension before this broke but I don't know which version works
It failed on deploying to azure and I have already signed in to Azure
[2024-08-09T11:14:55.162Z] [Info] - Executing deploy 

Lifecycle stage: deploy(3 step(s) in total). The following actions will be executed: 
(1/3) Action devTool/install: installing dependencies
(2/3) Action cli/runNpmCommand(install dependencies): running npm command.
(3/3) Action file/createOrUpdateEnvironmentFile: Create or update variables to environment file.

[2024-08-09T11:14:55.162Z] [Info] - Executing lifecycle deploy
[2024-08-09T11:15:41.109Z] [Warning] -  [script stderr] npm error code ETARGET

[2024-08-09T11:15:41.110Z] [Warning] -  [script stderr] npm error notarget No matching version found for node-fetch@^2.6.7.
npm error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

[2024-08-09T11:15:41.111Z] [Warning] -  [script stderr] 

[2024-08-09T11:15:41.112Z] [Warning] -  [script stderr] npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/thanaratjaruenying/.npm/_logs/2024-08-09T11_14_55_485Z-debug-0.log

[2024-08-09T11:15:41.125Z] [Error] - Failed to Execute lifecycle deploy due to failed action: {"name":"install dependencies","uses":"cli/runNpmCommand"}. ScriptExecutionError:Unable to execute script action.. Env output: {}
[2024-08-09T11:15:41.125Z] [Info] - Execution summary:

Summary:
(×) Error: Lifecycle stage deploy failed.
  (√) Done: devTool/install was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Azure Functions Core Tools is installed.
  (×) Error: cli/runNpmCommand(install dependencies) failed.
    (×) Error: Unable to execute script action.
  (!) Warning: file/createOrUpdateEnvironmentFile was not executed.



It seems that your npm install command failed to run successfully.
Please refer to Npm Error - No matching version found for to find how to fix this.
